# How do I fix this parse error in my PHP code?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, wampserver, parse-error

I just started PHP and I want to know how to fix this parse error. This is the error:

```
Parse error: parse error in E:\wamp\www\PHP\create.php on line 22
```

And here is my code. By the way, I'm making a database manipulating system, and I use WampServer and Dreamweaver.

```
<?php
    include 'E:\wamp\www\PHP\connection.php';

    $IDNUMBER = $_POST['ID'];
    $LNAME = $_POST['Lname'];
    $FNAME = $_POST['Fname'];
    $MNAME = $_POST['Mname'];
    $GRADEYR = $_POST['GradeYr'];
    $ADDRESS = $_POST['Address'];

    if (!$_POST['submit']) {
        echo "please fill out the form";
        header('Location: E:\wamp\www\PHP\main.php');
    } else {

        mysql_query = "INSERT INTO  students (`IDNUMBER`,`LNAME` ,`FNAME` ,`MNAME` ,`GRADEYR` ,`ADDRESS`)
        VALUES (NULL, '$IDNUMBER', '$LNAME', '$FNAME', '$MNAME', '$GRADEYR', '$ADDRESS')") or die(mysql_error());

        echo "User has been added!";
        header('E:\wamp\www\PHP\main.php');


    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query = "INSERT ....") or die(...);
```

You have an extra closing ")"; Remove it from there.

The code shoult look like 
    mysql_query("INSERT ....") or die(...);

if you want to insert something into the DB:)

Comment: like this?
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO students(`IDNUMBER`,`LNAME`,`FNAME`,`MNAME`,`GRADEYR`,`ADDRESS`)
                    VALUES (NULL, '$IDNUMBER', '$LNAME', '$FNAME', '$MNAME', '$GRADEYR', '$ADDRESS') or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query = "...
```

should be

```
mysql_query(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You also likely forgot to escape / sanitize the user input...

If the name or an address contains an ' you might have issues

Comment: yes, you should run mysql_real_escape_string() on every value you insert into the Query => $IDNUMBER = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);

Answer (score -1):

'$ADDRESS')") you have an extra bracket here. Check it dude.

Comment: [You are wrong!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrjwaqZfjIY) First bracket closes the `VALUES` inside the query and second bracket ends the `mysql_query`. [Check this dude.](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlinsert.php)